# Ag Grid react dropdown not showing outside grid

Tags: css, reactjs, ag-grid-react, react-bootstrap-typeahead

Using typeahead as cell editor for search, and in rows, and adding.

The problem is, when applying the typeahead for options, will show only inside the table.

I tried `overflow: visible` and it works that way

```
actions-button-cell:has(.MultiColumn) {
  overflow: visible;
}

.ag-cel:has(.MultiColumn)l {
  overflow: visible;
}

.ag-row:has(.MultiColumn) {
  z-index: 0;
}

.ag-row.ag-row-focus:has(.MultiColumn) {
  z-index: 1;
}


.ag-root:has(.MultiColumn),
.ag-root-wrapper:has(.MultiColumn),
.ag-body-viewport:has(.MultiColumn),
.ag-body-viewport-wrapper:has(.MultiColumn),
.ag-center-cols-clipper:has(.MultiColumn),
.ag-center-cols-viewport:has(.MultiColumn) {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

In css this will show the options without hiding but the scroll from the aggrid row is gone cuz of overflow:visible.

Is there a way to show the dropdown options outside of aggrid without removing the scroll

Any help will be appreciated

sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/v1cqbz

Comment: Have you tried the `positionFixed` prop on the Typeahead? That should allow the menu to render outside of the container. See: https://ericgio.github.io/react-bootstrap-typeahead/#positioning

Comment: @ericgio just tried but not seems to be working

Comment: i tried on a fresh project it works for one layer of cell editing but not for the full scrollable rows

Comment: Additional code or sandbox would be helpful

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/v1cqbz

Comment: Your sandbox doesn't seem to be working correctly for me; It's crashing the browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for aggrid columndef in the field you want to add cellEditorPopup: true
it will make the full typeahead and dropdown option come on top .

```json
columnDefs= [{field:"name",cellEditorPopup: true,cellEditor:"editorname"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

**One solution to this problem could be** to change the position of the typeahead dropdown menu to be absolutely positioned, rather than being inside the table.

This way, the dropdown menu can be displayed **outside of the table's overflow boundaries.**

You can do this by adding the following CSS to your code:

```
.typeahead-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2; /* make sure it is above the table */
}
```

You also might want to adjust the position of the dropdown menu by setting the **top** and **left** properties, to make sure it is positioned correctly in relation to the input field.

Comment: did not work the scroll stopped working and the typeahead was not opening

Comment: @CristoFerrao try without pointer none - removed that from answer also -  I realize its causing a problem

Comment: no doesn't work tried on https://codesandbox.io/s/v1cqbz?file=/src/App.css